# Simple network resource share inhibited by catch 22 password issue

Tags: network-share, file-sharing, user-management, windows-server-2016

This is a very basic network I'm dealing with in which one machine in an office is running Windows Server 2016 and currently acting as nothing more than a data server with plans to leverage it for remote applications in the future.

I setup several user accounts on the machine and have enabled sharing of one of the systems HDDs for "Everyone".  For each user, I checked the box for "User must reset password at first login".  This seemed to work fine for the first user who logged on but everyone else receive's an error message when mapping their network drive that "User must change password before login" but it doesn't prompt to change it...  Obviously, I can disable the check box on their user account that forces the password reset and they can log in just fine, but why can't they change their password from the "client" end?

This seems like a Catch-22 in that I want them to reset their passwords, but they can't unless they are logged in...  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an interactive logon for the change password prompt to be presented. Mapping a network drive is a a different kind of logon where the prompt is not used. If the server and the workstations were part of a domain, the users would get the prompt when they logged onto their workstation with their domain account, but it sounds like you are using local accounts.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The the accounts are all local to the machine.  Do you mind elaborating a bit on how I would go about creating the "interactive logon"?

Comment: An interactive logon is a logon to the machine where the account resides (in this case your server) via the keyboard or RDP.

Comment: Oh I see.. I guess what I meant is that the accounts were created on the server and are local to the server.  I had one user who mapped a network drive from a different pc and it asked for him to change his password as expected and everything worked.  Everyone else who has tried gets the "User's password must be changed before logging on the first time".  I do not have the server connected to a domain and I created everyone's account on the server.

Comment: I'm sure my terminology isn't great.  I am not a network admin.  Just wearing a couple hats right now...